# Is it true that if $\dim\mathbb{V}=n$, then $\mathbb{F}^n\cong\mathbb{V}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In this instance, we define $\mathbb{F}^n$ as follows. Suppose $\mathbb{F}$ is a field. Then we let $\mathbb{F}^n$ be the following vector space
$$
\mathbb{F}^n=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}:x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\in\mathbb{F}\right\}
$$
Now, suppose $\mathbb{V}$ is a vector space such that $\dim\mathbb{V}=n$. Then we may suppose that $\psi=\lbrace\vec{\varphi}_1,\vec{\varphi}_2,\cdots,\vec{\varphi}_n\rbrace$ be a basis for $\mathbb{V}$, and let
$$
\varepsilon=\lbrace\vec{e}_1,\vec{e}_2,\cdots,\vec{e}_n\rbrace=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix},\cdots,\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}
$$
Be a basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$ (this is the standard basis). To therefore show that $\mathbb{F}^n\cong\mathbb{V}$, we are required to find a $T:\mathbb{F}^n\to\mathbb{V}$ such that $T$ is both linear and bijective. For this purpose, we define $T$ as follows. Let $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{F}^n$. Then we may write
$$
\vec{x}=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j\vec{e}_j
$$
where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb{F}$. Then we let
$$
T(\vec{x})=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j\vec{\varphi}_j
$$
It can be easily shown that $T$ is injective. With this case, we have also that $T(\vec{e}_i)=\vec{\varphi}_j$. We therefore have that $\psi=\lbrace T(\vec{e}_1),T(\vec{e}_2),\cdots,T(\vec{e}_n)\rbrace$ is a basis for $\mathbb{V}$. My question is whether or not we can, from these facts, infer that $T$ is in fact bijective? Proving that if $\mathbb{F}^n\cong\mathbb{V}\implies\dim\mathbb{V}=n$ is rather straightfoward, and I have tried working back from this proof to show that $T$ is bijective, but have not succeeded in my task thus far. I also know that since $\dim\mathbb{V}=n$, if $T$ is either injective or surjective, then it is indeed also bijective. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you proved that $T$ is injective, you only left to prove that $T$ is surjective. If $\{\vec{\varphi}_1,\cdots,\vec{\varphi}_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{V}$, the for every $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{V}$ there are $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $\vec{x}=\sum^n_{j=1}\lambda_j\vec{\varphi}_j$, then $\vec{x}$ is the image of $(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)\in\mathbb{F}$

Comment: Indeed your idea is right for *finite-dimensional* vector space $\mathbb{V}$ (with $\dim(\mathbb{V})$ = n) over the same field $\mathbb{F}$ for which $V \cong_{\mathrm{vec}} \mathbb{F}^n$. A nice thing is that $\cong_{\mathrm{vec}}$ is an equivalence relation. Hence you can identify every finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ with $\mathbb{F}^n$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's true. 
Two spaces have the same dimension iff they are isomorphic.

Proof: Let $V, W$ be two spaces of the same dimension. Let $T: V\rightarrow W$ be the linear map that sends basis to basis, then the map is injective because the basis are linearly independent and surjective because the image of the linear map is spanned by the action on the basis. Hence, $\dim(\text{Im}T)=\dim W$. Since $\text{Im}T$ is a subspace of W, they must be equal. Thus you have constructed an isomorphism between the two spaces.

For the converse, suppose two finite dimensional spaces, V and $W$ are isomorphic, with isomorphism $T$. Then basis are sent to basis, hence the spaces have the same dimension.

An immediate corollary to this is the proposition you have mentioned because $\dim\mathbb{F}^n$=n